# Send ID of clicked item in table to server without AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I have a table containing multiple rows of data. The user can scroll through each row, click a row, and be prompted to do something with that row (update, delete, etc).

I'm able to get the id of the clicked row (the id is significant as it's the id of the model object) with Javascript and make an AJAX call to the server with the id however I can't figure out how to redirect to a page after the first server call without making a second trip to the server as AJAX needs a response.

So I'm trying to accomplish this without AJAX. Is there a way to pass the id of the row into the url (in the a-tag) of the modal below? Or is there a better pattern to accomplish this that I'm missing. This problem seems like it must have an obvious solution and I'm overthinking it...

Here's the pertinent code for my table.

Edit: I'm also using Django for my backend/template engine.

```
<tbody id="trip-request-table">
    {% for key in need_trips %}
    <tr id={{key.trip_ptr_id}} onClick="updateRow(this.id)">
        <td>{{key.created|date:'Y-m-d'}}</td>
        <td>{{key.user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{key.arrival_date|date:'Y-m-d'}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Here's the Javascript that grabs the id and fires a modal:

```
    function updateRow(id) {
        //alert('id: ' + id);
        var rowId = id;
        var modal = $('#manage-trip');

        var row = document.getElementById(id);
        var cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
        var arrivalCity;
        var departureDate;

        for (var i =0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            if(i == 4) {
                departureDate = moment(cells[i].innerHTML).format('MMMM Do, YYYY');
            } else if(i == 6) {
                arrivalCity = cells[i].innerHTML;
            } 
        }

        modal.find('.modal-body').text('Would you like to update your trip to ' + arrivalCity + ' on ' 
            + departureDate + '?');
        //updateRow.find('.modal-body input').val(id);
        modal.val(id);
        console.log('show modal');
        modal.modal('show');
        console.log('trip id: ' + id);

        $("#update-trip").off().click(function(event) {
            $('#manage-trip').modal('hide');
            var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var processData = true;
            var endpoint = "{% url 'trips:updateTripGet' pk=1 %}";
            var payload = false;

            updateTrip(contentType, processData, endpoint, payload);
        });

    }
```

Here's the modal code:

```
<div class="modal" id="manage-trip" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Edit your trip</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="{% url 'members:updateTrip' %}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="update-trip">Update</button>-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-trip">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If so, you need to provide what backend&templates you uses such as Django, flask .etc?

Comment: @Sphinx Django. Thanks.

Comment: If .Net. you sure can do this. But for Django, I don't think it supports the viewstate and server controls (even some middleware of Django can do it, but it must not be easy). [.Net ViewState Mechanism](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-view-state-and-how-it-works-in-Asp-Net53/)

Comment: it's not very clear what your question is still.  Are you trying to pass the ID to the modal without having to request it from the server?  Depending on what modal library you are using, you can probably tie in to a lifecycle event and when the modal loads, execute a function that updates the relevant section with the id.

Comment: @EugeneG If you look at the Javascript code I get the id from the row that was clicked on. I'm trying to send that id to the server...ideally as an argument in the link for the a-tag in the modal.

Comment: Can't you simply submit a form on click event with ID to server??

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was by having the modal trigger this block of code:

```
$("#update-trip").off().click(function(event) {
    $('#manage-trip').modal('hide');
    var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var endpoint = "{% url 'members:updateTrip' %}";
    var payload = false;

    //updateTrip(contentType, processData, endpoint, payload);
    submitForm(contentType, endpoint, rowId);
});
```

That code block calls a function that dynamically creates a form and submits it to the server. I guess this is just another obvious solution to most web developers but I'm noob af. I'm sure I'll clean this up some just stoked it works.

The nice thing about this solution is you avoid having to create forms in each table row, etc.

```
function submitForm(contentType, endpoint, rowId) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");

    form.method = "POST";
    form.enctype = contentType;
    form.action = endpoint;
    element1.type = 'hidden';
    element1.value= rowId;
    element1.name= "trip_id";
    form.appendChild(element1);
    element2.type = 'hidden';
    element2.value= '{{ csrf_token }}';
    element2.name= 'csrfmiddlewaretoken';
    form.appendChild(element2);

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
}
```